# Want to check how a particular user has interacted with you on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, chat, moderator-election

Can we have a section on User profile's page which shows how a particular user has been interacted with you?

**For example** if I go to a user's profile, a section should show what answers, comments or flags user had contributed to my posts.
This can be good way to know a user better, especially when a user is electing for community moderator election.

Basically you get to know the User better which can lead to selection of most deserved moderator.

Do we have this kind of page/section? If not then I think it will be very beneficial in many ways if we add this kind of section.

Comment: If you haven't seen it, you might be interested in the ["Have we met?"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/25355/have-we-met) query. Not quite as powerful as what you ask for here, but still interesting.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic Oh Wow that's interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

No, let's not turn this site into a cozy place where we socialize and work on our social network. There are plenty of other venues outside of the SE network that facilitate exactly what you want.

On top of that, sharing which flags I have contributed on your posts would be a breach of the confidentiality flags have. I can have raised plenty of rude and abusive flags against your posts and it would be pretty easy to deduct that from the then public info.

I don't see how knowing the user and their network better helps in electing a moderator. All you should care for is how they contribute to make SO the canonical knowledgebase for generations of developers to come. That needs established content moderation skills, not a popular vote among your peers.

Comment: hmm agree with you to some extent.